# Laravel custom login is failing for the first time with "route [login] not defined" error. Working fine in second attempt

Tags: laravel, laravel-authorization

I'm setting up my custom authentication system in my Laravel app. I've deleted all the default auth controllers and not using make::auth. And my auth is working properly. My main problem is that when I tried to log in for the first time, it's failing with "Route [login] not defined" error, but in second attempt, it's working properly. And if I repeat the process, it's continuing again and again like the first two attempt. Actually, I've never used login route anywhere.

Here is my form:

```
<form action="{{ url('/log-in') }}" method="POST">

@csrf

<input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Telefon" class="form-control input-phone">

<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Parol" class="form-control">

<button type="submit" class="btn">Kirish</button>

</form>
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::post('/log-in', 'AuthController@login');
```

Here is my controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\User;

class AuthController extends Controller
{


    public function login(Request $request) {

        // Get current user.
        $user = User::where('phone', $request->phone)
                       ->first();

        if ( Hash::check($request->password, $user['password']) ) {

            Auth::login($user, true);
            Auth::logoutOtherDevices($request->password);
            return redirect()->back();
        }   
    }

}
```

Comment: if you want custom auth then remove Auth::routes() from web.php and change redirect url for unauthenticated user in RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware Route [login] not defined this fil fix after change RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware

Comment: I've already deleted Auth::routes() from my web.php. And now changed redirect url from "/home" to "/" in RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware. But still getting the same error.

Comment: run this command and try again php artisan route:cache

Comment: Get this error: Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure

Comment: you can also clear your route cache by deleting all folder inside path : \storage\framework\cache\data 

delete all folder inside : data and view folder

Comment: I do not have any folder in this folder

Answer (score 0):

Use for route.

```
Route::post('/log-in', 'AuthController@login')->name('login');
```

Use your form.

```
<form action="{{ route('login') }}" method="POST">

    @csrf

    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Telefon" class="form-control input-phone">

    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Parol" class="form-control">

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Kirish</button>

    </form>
```

Comment: I've done before and done again. Now, getting this error: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. But, I'm using POST method.

Comment: If you use Route::any() GET and POST provide supports.

Comment: I've tried it, I did not get error message, but not logging in. Just returning blank page for the first attempt. And logging properly in second attempt

Comment: I think, actually, it is not an error which is related to route.

Comment: Where is your login blade ?

Comment: I do not have login blade. I have a login form in every page as pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky and annoying problem. you need to change your return from `return redirect()->back();` to loading 1 known blade or a known redirect. Sometimes at login your route fails to set a back redirect. so you can try to set a `return view()` or a return to a  known url. So for example if the login is success return to index , if not load error page.

Hope this helps

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. But, still getting the same error.

Comment: did you do a php artisan cache:clear ? also where are you trying to redirect to ? a page or a link or a view ?

Comment: also are you suing a middleware ?

Comment: I've done php artisan cache:clear and I'm redirecting to route named "dashboard". Code: return redirect()->route('dashboard');

Comment: if you are not using a middleware and cache:clear didn't help. try : Route::post('login', [ 'as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AuthController@login']);

and in your form call the login name

Comment: did you add Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
//routes

});

Comment: do you have a login blade ?

Comment: Nope, I have login pop-up in every blade.

Comment: for a test make a login blade and a     Route::get('/login', function () {
        return view('login');

    });

and check if it works. if yes then we need to change your route to work with the popup if not then we need to debug more

Comment: I've done it. I did not get error, but not logging in for the first time again.

Comment: ok keep using it and try to check why your logging is failing. set your form in that page try to make the whole login process in it and see what result you get. (to make sure everything is working right).

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll publish the error and solution, when I find it.